# observable.subscribe(..).unsubscribe(); anti-pattern.

Tags: rxjs

I've been finding myself writing code that looks like this:

```
class WidgetService {

   getWidgets() {
       return this.authService.user.pipe(  //authService.user is an Observable, that emits the currently authenticated users. 
         first(user => user!=null),  //Make sure a null object isn't coming through
         switchMap(user => {
            return this.collection.getWhere("widget.ownerId", "==", user.id); //Get all the widgets for that user
         })
       ); 
   }

}

class WidgetDisplayComponent {

    ngOnInit() {
       this.widgetService.getWidget().subscribe(widget => this.widget = widget).unsubscribe(); //Subscribe to cause the Observable to pipe, get the widget, then unsubscribe. 
    }
}
```

Is this an anti pattern? What should I be doing instead, where the requirements are:

- In order to get the item I'm fetching, I need to rely on another Observable.
- I only need to get this item once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that it is absolutely an anti-pattern, for these reasons:

- With synchronous sources, there is no guarantee that you will receive only one `next` notification.
- With asynchronous sources, you won't receive any `next` notifications - as the subscriber will be synchronously unsubscribed.

The pattern would only work for synchronous sources that emit only a single `next` notification. In which case, the `unsubscribe` is redundant, as the subscriber will be automatically unsubscribed when the source completes.

IMO, if you know that the source emits only one `next` notification, you should just omit the `unsubscribe`. If you are unsure, you should use either `first` or `take(1)` at the subscription point.

---

There is another mechanism that can be used to unsubscribe upon receipt of the first `next` notification, but it's not one that I would encourage, as it requires a non-arrow function to be used.

The subscriber is used as the context when the `next` handler is invoked, so it's possible to call `unsubscribe` on it, like this:

```
source.subscribe(function (value) {
  /* do something with value */
  this.unsubscribe();
});
```

Comment: Correct, use `take(1)` then you don't have to `unsubscribe()`.

Comment: @Envil It depends on what you want: `first` and `take(1)` are different. `first` will error for sources that complete without emitting a `next` notification; `take(1)` will not.

Comment: yes I know. I'm not trying to list the possible operator here.